# How to return product collection from block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

I want to get product collection in my block using dependency injection. How I can do it?
I've tried following code but it doesn't work.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;

    }
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->productCollection->load(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }
```